# Circular dependency fix

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

I'm sure this is some design flaw on my part mainly because I come from a Java background. But it is what it is.

Here's the setup in general:

I have a class lets say `A` with `#include "B.h"`

```
#include "B.h"

class A {

    // stuff
private:
    B _b;

}
```

Additionally I have class `B` with `#include "C.h"`

```
#include "C.h"

class B {

    // more stuff

private:
    C::EnumType _cEnum;
}
```

And lastly I have class `C` with `#include "A.h"`

```
#include "A.h"

class C {
public:
    C(A a);
    enum EnumType {
        // enum stuff
    };

    // more stuff

}
```

How can I fix this? I've tried some business with forward declarations but it didn't seem to work, though I don't claim that I did it correctly. Namespaces maybe?

Comment: I suggest you to rework your interfaces according to Dependency Inversion Principle, that is there should be no dependencies in counter directions and cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried some business with forward declarations but it didn't seem to work

You didn't show us what "didn't seem to work", or in what way it "didn't seem to work", but there is *one* place in your code where you can replace a full type definition with a forward declaration, and two where you can't.

#### Where you can't

Non-static data members must be of complete types:

> `[C++11: 9.2/10]:` Non-`static` (9.4) data members shall not have incomplete types. In particular, a class `C` shall not contain a non-static member of class `C`, but it can contain a pointer or reference to an object of class `C`.

So, the `B` in `A`and the `C::EnumType` in `B` cannot be forward declared.

**BTW:** This is not the case for `static` data members, which *can* be forward declared:

> `[C++11: 9.4.2/2]:` The declaration of a `static` data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified `void`.

#### Where you can

However, the same is not true of the types of parameters in a member function declaration, so you can forward-declare the `A` in `C(A a)`:

```
class A;

class C {
public:
    C(A a);
    enum EnumType {
        // enum stuff
    };

    // more stuff
};
```

`#include` as little into headers as you possibly can.

#### Why you shouldn't need to

> I'm sure this is some design flaw on my part mainly because I come from a Java background

I don't see that Java has anything to do with it but, yes, your design seems flawed in the way that these classes all depend on each other. Perhaps `C::EnumType` should instead be `B::EnumType`? Try to make your classes more self-contained. Forward declarations are all well and good, but life would be a lot easier if you solved the root problem of your design's tight coupling.

Comment: "You have nothing that can be forward declared, mainly because C's constructor takes an A by value. ". This is incorrect. Please fix.

Comment: Race to the light in my answer's orbit.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes I did. You need to carefully read my answer to find my reply.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Thanks for being so cryptic as to rudely waste my time. I asked you a simple question. Anyway, turns out you're right, and I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @user1047930: Unlikely. It's still best as a reference-to-const, though it _doesn't need to be_ (as it turns out).

Comment: @Light i edited my answer only to answer your question. Then I pointed you to my question to spot it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Nothing in your answer _explicitly_ addresses my doubts (e.g. with an affirmation, or with a citation); it only asserts what I'd already asserted the opposite of, which is not useful when contested.

Comment: @Ligh hmm i thought "Only the definition of C::C needs its parameter type to have a definition." answers. I'm sorry that I was being unclear apparently :(

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes, but it's not enough. I'd already contested it. Answering my disagreement requires more than cryptically redirecting me to the statement that I'd initially contested. "The sky's blue." "No, it's red." "No, you're wrong." "Why?" "See my first statement." ">.<" | Anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241255/where-is-the-standard-wording-allowing-incomplete-types-in-function-declarations

Comment: Nono it's like this I think: "Your head is brown." "No it's not." "Why?" "Only the hair on my head is brown.".

Comment: Thank you!! I wish I could accept yours and Johannes' answer!

Answer (score 3):

In C, you don't need to include A. Only the other two headers need their include directives you put there.

```
class A;

class C {
public:
    C(A a);
    enum EnumType {
        // enum stuff
    };

    // more stuff
};
```

Put the definition of `C::C` into a `.cpp` file where you can include `A.h` then. Only the definition of `C::C` needs its parameter type to have a definition.

Comment: -1: You can't forward declare a type when copying an object of that type.

Comment: @Lightness: A function *declaration* does not count. The parameter types must only be complete types at the call site or when the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

@Lightness says it - you don't need to include a.h into C's compilation unit if you declare class A using a 'forward' definition. Just put 'class A;' into the header which tells the compiler (and linker) to figure out what A is at a later time. The only disadvantage to this is that file C no longer knows what's inside of A, so you have to use references or pointers.

An alternative is just to split C into 2 parts. Is there a reason the enum in embedded inside it, and not part of B? If C and B share the enum definitions, then it should be split into a separate class, or just be an top-level enum by itself.

When I get circular definitions like this, I double check what it is that I'm doing. I always find that I've made things a bit too complicated for myself.